I want to do mathematics similar to style of Grothendieck. How is that possible?
I am a person who enjoys math. Out of interest, I would like to ask a (soft) question. One of the reasons that I am posting this question is because in doing mathematics, it is hard to get rid of the impression that solving problems is not everything in math (True ?) - although I like solving problems -. Please understand my ignorance and somewhat vagueness through this question.
I admire Grothendieck's style of mathematics and want to do mathematics like his style. For example,

Generalization of things by discarding unnecessary hypotheses, which leads to simplification. ( Slogan: In generalizing, I was simplifying )

Underwater work: making solvents in which solutions or proofs come out by themselves naturally.

Accomplishment of fundamental transform and redefine foundation of mathematics (in particular algebraic geometry).

Creation of new mathematics and achieving revolutionary innovation (He would aim at finding and creating the 'home', which was the problem's natural habitat).

Painting landscape (highway) in which proofs become obvious and natural.

Finding new hidden structures so that the solution would come out by itself.

Rewrite the existing mathematical language into a new language (transformation of mathematics).

Conceptual way of doing mathematics ($\divideontimes$ instead of solving problems by tricks, more or less fortuitous stroke of genius, you may work conceptually on the theories to understand how you can generalize them in order to solve a problem that in that theory appears impossible, and in the more generalized version of it will appear trivial. This is the difference between 'tricky' mathematics and conceptual Mathematics.)

Grand unification.

Solving problems as a test of general vision.


Etc...
How can we achieve or implement these styles/ideals of mathematics? Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a simple and clear way/know-how? By selecting some 'good' problems (with discerning for cognizing good problems) and trying to solve them, like the Galois theory? An issue that makes me confused is when I try to approach this ideal directly, I feel like my mind is being distracted. I don't know how to use the power of the unconscious to its full potential in harmony with the above directions. Is problem selection and solving necessary, even as a means of focus?
Perhaps new theories come naturally in the process of solving problems?
Let me upload a few quotes about this issue:

"He who seeks for methods without having a definite problem in mind seeks for the most part in vain" - David Hilbert.

"Unfortunately, it is impossible to find the right definitions by pure thought; one needs to detect the correct problems where progress will require the isolation of a new key concept." - Peter Scholze.

On the other hand, there is also a quote like next: "Then around 1956–1958 Grothendieck began to work in algebraic geometry, a field with a rich history, and with already many existing theories. He told us that this was because he was planning to solve the Weil
conjectures. However, do not interpret this as "problem-solving". On many occasions, Grothendieck told us
that finding the structure involved was the only essential thing to do, and then the solution would come out
by itself: "immerse a large nut in a softening fluid, and the nut opens just by itself. We have seen many
instances where going to the very roots and pure thought gave insight and solved difficult problems." - Life and Work of Alexander Grothendieck by Ching-Li Chai.


Etc...
Do you understand what my problem is? This may be ignorant, but I want to do math with 70% theory (architecture) building and $30\%$ problem-solving. I want to do math in full sense ! I don't know what to do in loneliness. Do I need to interact with other mathematicians? Can anyone advise? Thanks for reading.

My impression is that there are a lot of people doing exactly that. For example, if you look at the very popular site nLab, that's almost exclusively theory building.

Honestly, it might sound harsh, but Grothendieck would never have gone on an online forum to ask strangers if his approach to mathematics was correct or needed fixing. You have to do what works for you. I, and others, don't know you enough to pinpoint what’s wrong—you’ll need to figure that out yourself.

@huh : Huh. Yes, I think what you say also makes sense. And.. This is something I thought about quite a bit before posting. It seems like it's related to a sensitive issue within me, and I'm actually a little nervous about asking questions in public. Anyway thank you..

Read a lot, do plenty of exercises, and don’t worry about these other things. It takes time, just keep going.

@Stefan : Aha, really? I think It is first time to see such perspective. I feel like my horizons have broadened.

This is an interesting question! Timothy Gowers did a lecture which explored theory building in mathematics vs problem solving, exploring these two different ways of approaching mathematics. You might find it useful: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/2cultures.pdf

Problem solving and Theory building are both essential in math.  Watch out for the danger that each side will look down on the other, considering it less important.

@GEdgar : O.K. I got it. Thank you.

Your assertion that problems aren't everything seems to contradict the quotes that you include.

Mathematics is highly collaborative, and Jo Boaler wrote on how learning maths collaboratively is associated with high achievement.
You might enjoy writings of Eugenia Cheng, who wrote on theory building versus problem solving in mathematics. Her work is highly accessible and makes mathematics accessible.
Category theory is something you might want to look into, as it studies the underlying patterns and relationships of mathematics. Learning mathematics with some understanding of category theory, I notice recurring patterns all over the place, whereas before mathematics looked quite dispersed.
I didn't personally liked mathematical problem solving much either, but with abstract mathematics (and a multidimensional approach) in mind even the simplest algebraic transformations become very interesting.
Here is the reference from x + y: A Mathematician's Manifesto for Rethinking Gender by Eugenia Cheng:

"Mathematician Sir Tim Gowers writes of the ’two cultures of mathematics’, which he characterises as problem-solving and theory-building.
It seems to me that in the wider world, mathematics is seen as all about problem-solving, and that theory-building is mostly unheard of or otherwise neglected. Of course, the two are not cleanly separate, and in the end I think mathematics is most satisfying when the two come together: where building a theory also solves some problems. But what does it mean to ’build a theory’?
Mathematical theories are descriptive, not prescriptive. They describe something that we see happening at the root of a situation, but they are not only there to predict how the situation will unfold. More broadly, they are there to help us think differently about the situation, to illuminate it, to help us understand how certain aspects of it are functioning. The theory is abstract — we have disregarded some of the surface details, to see what is happening inside.
In mathematics a theory often starts with an idea or a possibility, and is built up as a collection of conclusions about that idea, or consequences of that idea, or properties of that idea. Sometimes it’s really just a reframing of an existing idea, but a slight reframing can lead to a monumentally different theory. If you stand at the top of the building formerly called the Hancock Center in Chicago you can look across the city and see a vast jungle of ‘civilisation’ sprawling out to the horizon. But if you just shift your angle a tiny bit so that you’re looking straight down Michigan Avenue, the jungle becomes a grid system that will suddenly spring up before your eyes in near-perfect alignment. Sometimes in life all it takes is a slight shift in perspective, and this is often how new mathematical theories arise too."

